# CKEditor Show HTML Code using Youtube plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, youtube, ckeditor

I installed CKEditor, YouTube plugin and Iframe plugin, the video shows up and I can even play the video when I was creating. But when I want to save the page it displays this code HTML.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ykCZtyks6NY" width="640"></iframe>
```

[image]

I hope you can help me,

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So what is the issue? Looks like youtube in an iframe....

Comment: @epascarello I don't want to see the code only the video

Comment: what youtube plugin do you using ?

Comment: can you describe on what kind of platform you are using ckeditor? would it happen to be django? with djangocms?